# How to connect a SATA disk through GPIO (not USB)

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I repost this here because i was told on stackoverflow that my question was off-topic.

I would like to connect a lot of SATA hdd on my raspberry PI. I've read about how are sata pins made and I can create a power source myself. But i'd like to connect the hard disk through raspberry's GPIO, and to access it. But I have no idea of how I can control my disk directly with SATA signals. Is there any source code I could adapt to mount my wierdly-connected disk on the raspberry pi. I don't need a fast connection, the purpose is to save data. I can do the electronics requiered, and I have already a SATA cable which I can connect to the raspberry. My question is just about the software-side of the problem. At least, is it possible (can GPIO reach frequencies requiered by SATA protocol, for example).

Thanks for reading my bad english

Comment: You should not waste any further time on this. It is impractical - a task only [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) would undertake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how this can be done.  Even if it could it would probably be a serious waste of time and money.

SATA uses GHz signalling.  The Pi's GPIO function in the say 30Mhz range.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA

The simplest thing to do is to use a SATA to USB hardware interface and use the Pi's USB ports.